# Plone - attach multiple files

Tags: plone

I do not have much experience with plone, I searched on other forums an answer to my problem but without success. I saw that with plone you can enter text via "Add" event, news, page, file .... is to add a file that I have encountered a problem, that I can not add more files. I need to add multiple files with a single description, there is a way to do it?

Thank you !

Comment: Single description? Say more about your use case to help us understand this.

Comment: Could you get any further/something unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you are looking for a possibility to batch-upload files into a folder, there are several add-ons for help out there. I live happily with collective.quickupload, but you might want to make your own choice and have a look at the other products, too, as for example:

- wildcard.foldercontents (this will be the default behaviour in Plone 5)
- ATMassloader
- collective.upload
- collective.uploadify
- PloneFlashUpload
- PloneJUpload (Java)
- sc.base.uploader

Also: Plone/Zope has a native FTP/WebDAV-support. You can connect to a running Plone using a Webdav client, upload files and see them loaded in the CMS.

Additionally plone.formwidget.multifile allows you to add a file-field to your contenttype, which is capable to select multiple files at once for the upload in one single file-field. Haven't seen an out-of-the-box integration into a contenttype around, though, just in case you'd like to do it :-)

Might be interesting, too in this context:

- Browse-able ZIP
- collective.archiveviewer

Comment: wildcard.foldercontents works, is well-maintained, and is the basis for this feature's implementation in Plone 5.

Comment: @SteveM: Excellent point, could be posted as an answer. Probably also a good precondition for a smooth upgrade in the future? And less work with maintaining 3rd-party-add-ons.

Comment: @keul: I've just seen you did an edit-suggestion and it was rejected by SO-moderators. I have not enough reputation to review a suggestion, but include yours now to the answer, thanks for complementing, too!