# Plone: TinyMCE upload files

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying to find a solution for files uploading directly with TinyMCE. Imagine creating a list of pdf files by uploading them using a custom button.

Is there something already done I can use? collective.clipboardupload seems to be a solution only for images.

Comment: CastleCMS has that ability to let you upload files/images directly when editing with TinyMCE...

Comment: Relates to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348423/plone-attach-multiple-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[collective.quickupload](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.quickupload) serves us well for such purposes and has a very good UI.

You can add that gadget as a portlet and make it only visible in edit-mode via CSS.

In our case we assigned the portlet to a certain content-type ('Gallery') instead to a location.

Comment: Great. Thanks! What about collective.upload vs. collective.quickupload?

Comment: You won't have the upload-option available in edit-mode, using a popup is not so much encouraged anymore these days, and it pins plone.app.jquery to 1.8.3, which might not be compatible with your Plone-vs.

Comment: both packages are mature, but collective.upload use case is different indeed; modals (which are different from pop-ups) are totally fine: that's the way the standard insert image feature works on TinyMCE out of the box; we never think about having a plugin for it.

Comment: I was using the blurry term popup in the way it is most commonly understood: Referring to the UX, not the technical implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[MoxieManager](http://www.moxiemanager.com/) may be what you're looking for. It's a premium plugin made by the same developers as TinyMCE itself.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/enterprise/manage-files-and-images/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use reponsive file manager :
http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/